# Mindscape Web Workbench missing Sass SCSS Style Sheet template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, mindscape

I am using Visual Studio Community 2013 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 (with Web Essentials 2013 installed.

I downloaded Mindscape Web Workbench extension for visual studio. As it claims here: http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench/getting-started#content 
, it is supposed to install Sass SCSS style sheet template (the one highlighted in the photo in the link). However it is missing. The coffeeScript and Less Templates are installed normally. What can I do to bring back that specific template?

Answer (score 0):

Although the template doesn't appear when using File->New File (probably a bug), I can add SCSS files through the Solution Explorer.(I have Web Development Environment settings)